# Lotus Notes throws NotesException: Database open failed (%1)

Tags: web-services, lotus-notes, lotus-domino

I am running a web service from an instance of Salesforce to our client's Lotus Notes server. I am able to get hard-coded content to return, so I feel certain that the connection itself is working as intended.

However, as noted in the subject, I am running into a NotesException. This is being thrown on the last line of the code below (db and path are simply parameters I pass into the function, I am able to view records from the nsf they correspond to):

```
s = WebServiceBase.getCurrentSession();
Database data = s.getDatabase(db, path);
data.open();
```

If I try not opening the database, I get an exception that says I need to open the database. We had been developing this web service for a while without ever opening the database or knowing that this was something to concern ourselves with. Obviously something changed, but as my office is full of Salesforce devs and not LN devs, we don't know what.

Any help in tracking down the root cause of this issue would be greatly appreciated.

Edit:

Comments want to know what I meant by hardcoded content. The function returns a 2d String array, so it would be something like:

```
result[0][0] = "Hello World";
return result;
```

Comment: Can this answer help? http://stackoverflow.com/a/15454326/785061

Comment: Unfortunately not, the main difference is that by the time SF connects to LN. A session already exists. So that answer must apply to a different scenario.

Comment: Ah, true. Does the user instantiating the session have access to the database in question?

Comment: We have a few client servers we're trying to access. One definitely has the appropriate ID in the access control list. There other does not, but we suspect our ID file is part of an access group that is in that list. Either way, both servers give us the same exception.

Comment: Please explain what you mean by 'able to get hard coded content to return'. I.e., show us what code does work, so we at least know what you're comparing against.

Answer (score 0):

The Problem is that the db ist not found. So try to change the path from the db. 
if your db is in a folder on the server give the path for the folder in java. 
Your path variable must have the right format.