# ExtLibUtil.getCurrentSessionAsSigner open mail.box

Tags: xpages, javabeans

Opening mail.box with ExtLibUtil.getCurrentSessionAsSigner does not work for mail.box.

All elements are signed with the same id.

I'd like to copy mails, created by Anonymous, to mail.box. Any ideas, workarounds?

```
package de.egvpb.surveys;

import java.io.Serializable;

import lotus.domino.Database;
import lotus.domino.Session;

import com.ibm.xsp.extlib.util.ExtLibUtil;

public class SessionAsSignerBean implements Serializable{
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    private Database mailBoxDb ;

    public SessionAsSignerBean(){
        this.mailBoxDb = this.getMailBoxDbAsSigner() ;
    }

    private Database getMailBoxDbAsSigner() {
        Session s = ExtLibUtil.getCurrentSessionAsSigner() ;
        Database result = null ;
        Database currentDb = null ;
        String server = "" ;
        String filepath = "" ;
        try {
            // Anonymous has reader access for currentDb; database is opend
            currentDb = s.getCurrentDatabase() ;
            if( currentDb.isOpen() ) {
                System.out.println( "getMailBoxDbAsSigner, currentDB is open: " + currentDb.getFilePath() + " on " + currentDb.getServer() );
            } else {
                System.out.println( "getMailBoxDbAsSigner, currentDB is NOT open");
            }
            server = currentDb.getServer() ;
            // Anonymous has no Access for names.nsf; database is opend
            filepath = "names.nsf" ;
            result = s.getDatabase(server, filepath) ;
            if( result.isOpen() == false ) {
                System.out.println( "getMailBoxDbAsSigner, failed to open database " + filepath + " on " + server );
            } else {
                System.out.println( "getMailBoxDbAsSigner, database opend " + filepath + " on " + server );
            }

            // Anonymous has no Access for mail.box; database is NOT opend
            filepath = "mail.box" ;
            result = s.getDatabase(server, filepath) ;
            if( result.isOpen() == false ) {
                System.out.println( "getMailBoxDbAsSigner, failed to open database " + filepath + " on " + server );
            } else {
                System.out.println( "getMailBoxDbAsSigner, opend database " + filepath + " on " + server );
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace() ;
        }
        return result ;
    }

    // ====

    public Database getMailBoxDb() {
        return mailBoxDb;
    }

    public void setMailBoxDb(Database mailBoxDb) {
        this.mailBoxDb = mailBoxDb;
    }


}
```

Comment: It would be helpful to know what exactly "does not work". What kind of exception is raised? What is written to the console?

Comment: Also, I would first check if `result==null` and afterwards check the value of `result.open()` instead of `result.isOpen()`. Even though `NotesSession.getDatabase` should automatically open the database you would be on the safe side using the open() function.

Comment: [0F70:000E-16B4] 12.07.2017 10:54:36   HTTP JVM: getMailBoxDbAsSigner, currentDB is open: SessionAsSigner.nsf on CN=dev01/O=Hubi
[0F70:000E-16B4] 12.07.2017 10:54:36   HTTP JVM: getMailBoxDbAsSigner, database opend names.nsf on CN=dev01/O=Hubi
[0F70:000E-16B4] 12.07.2017 10:54:39   HTTP JVM: getMailBoxDbAsSigner, failed to open database mail.box on CN=dev01/O=Hubi

Comment: result is not null. 'result.open()' gives : 'NotesException: Database open failed (%1)'

Comment: You could try getting the db with `s.getDatabase((String) null,filepath)` as described here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15445297/fail-to-open-database-using-java-notes-api

Comment: Bingo! s.getDatabase((String) null,filepath) works. mail.box is opend. Thx!

Comment: `s.getServerName()` is better than passing `(String) null`. If you know and can verify the server name you're passing, you can troubleshoot more effectively than a "black box" default you can't verify, as has been shown here.

Answer (score 0):

I can't see anything wrong in your code, although for best practice I would recommend setting `server` to `s.getServerName()`, "" has different meanings for XPiNC.

Does your signer have access to mail.box? This should work and I've used such code before, amongst other places in XPages OpenLog Logger. If there are multiple mail.box databases set up, Domino will automatically still get the relevant one.

Comment: Signer has manager access to mail.box, but the the signer certifier is different from the (test-) server certifier. Might this be the cause?

Comment: I'm not sure. Querying the access for that ID via ACL or database APIs may help confirm.